# Get a shell to the pi with no shared wifi and only using ethernet

Tags: networking, wifi

WHen I flash my firmware, I had set up the wifi SSID and password to use the pi in my local LAN. How can I have a shell to the pi if im not in my local LAN? Say if I don't have wifi on my local host machine, can I get a shell to the pi? If I'm connected to a different LAN, how can I get a shell to the pi to configure the LAN settings on my pi?

Thanks

Comment: Connect the pI to the local ethernet switch and SSH? Console cable/usb to serial converter. https://www.adafruit.com/?q=serial+friend&gclid=CjwKCAjwv-GUBhAzEiwASUMm4rFv4LSKGxdUXDl9UbAvfg0noiq0AGajmVeGRsEtWFtqbVFsvkroERoCJtQQAvD_BwE&sort=BestMatch, https://www.adafruit.com/product/954?gclid=CjwKCAjwv-GUBhAzEiwASUMm4rFv4LSKGxdUXDl9UbAvfg0noiq0AGajmVeGRsEtWFtqbVFsvkroERoCJtQQAvD_BwE

Comment: Basically, the question is how routing works. Such an explanation would be too broad for a Q&A site.